Understanding Church's proof there is no effectively computable algorithm to decide if two lambda expressions are convertable
I'm trying to understand Church's proof mentioned in this brief wiki summary, as mentioned in this question

Church's proof of uncomputability first reduces the problem to determining whether a given lambda expression has a normal form. Then he assumes that this predicate is computable, and can hence be expressed in lambda calculus. Building on earlier work by Kleene and constructing a Gödel numbering for lambda expressions, he constructs a lambda expression e that closely follows the proof of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem. If e is applied to its own Gödel number, a contradiction results.

I don't know where "If e is applied to its own Gödel number, a contradiction results" is coming from.
The original paper has more details (page 361-362)

THEOREM XVIII ...
...We are to deduce a contradiction from the assumption that it is effectively determinable of every well-formed formula whether or not it has a normal form. If this
assumption holds, it is effectively determinable of every well-formed formula whether or not it is convertible into one of the formulas 1, 2, 3, ... ; for, given a well-formed formula $\mathbf{R}$, we can first determine whether or not it has a normal form, and if it has we can obtain the principal normal form by enumerating the formulas into which $\mathbf{R}$ is convertible (Theorem XII) and picking out the first formula in principal normal form which occurs in the enumeration, and we can then determine whether the principal normal form is one of the formulas 1, 2, 3, ... Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ be an effective enumeration of the well-formed formulas which have a normal form (Theorem XV).
Let $E$ be a function of one positive integer, defined by the rule that, where $\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are the formulas which stand for the positive integers $m$ and $n$ respectively, $E(n) = 1$ if $\{A_n\}(n)$ is not convertible into one of the formulas 1,2,3, ..., and $E(n) = m + 1$ if $\{A_n\} (n)$ [convertable into] $\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ is one of the formulas 1, 2, 3, .... The function $E$ is effectively calculable and is therefore $\lambda$-definable, by a formula $\mathfrak{e}$. The formula $\mathfrak{e}$ has a normal form, since $\mathfrak{e}(1)$ has a normal form. But $\mathfrak{e}$ is not any one of the formulas $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ because, for every $n$, $\mathfrak{e}(n)$ is a formula which is not convertible into $\{A_n\}(n)$. And this contradicts the property of the enumeration $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ that it contains all well-formed formulas which have a normal form.

Q: I'm somehow not understanding 1) $\mathfrak{e}(1)$ has a normal form (how do we know this?), and 2) why "$\mathfrak{e}$ is not any one of the formulas $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$, " because I thought that was a list of well-formed formulas which have a normal form.
Church, Alonzo (1936). "An unsolvable problem of elementary number theory". American Journal of Mathematics. 58 (2): 345–363. doi:10.2307/2371045. JSTOR 2371045.

pdf of Church's paper: https://ics.uci.edu/~lopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/church.pdf

$\mathfrak{e}(1)$ has a normal form because it is specified to be calculating $E(1)$, which is defined to be either $1$ or $2$, depending on the behavior of $\{A_1\}(1)$.

$\mathfrak{e}$ cannot be equivalent to any $A_n$ because it is specified so that $\mathfrak{e}(n)$ is always different from $\{A_n\}(n)$. If $\{A_n\}(n)$ has no normal form, or has a normal form that doesn't represent a number, $\mathfrak{e}(n)$ does (it's $1$, which is a number). If $\{A_n\}(n)$ has a normal form that represents a number ($m$), $\mathfrak{e}(n)$ has one that represents a different number ($m+1$).
Remember, this is a proof that the normalization predicate is not decidable. So, as part of building $\mathfrak{e}$, we have assumed something false. That we can subsequently prove there is a normalizing term that isn't on the enumeration of all normalizing terms is the desired contradiction used to refute that there can be such a decider.
